# Monoidal product in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm considering to learn Haskell to do some specific task. I want to do monoidal product:

Suppose `f:A -> B` and `g: C -> D` are functions, and I want to do a monoidal product:

```
f * g : A * C -> B * D
```

Is this easily implementable in Haskell? If so, can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell spells the Cartesian product type (your `*`) as `(,)`, as in `(Int, Bool)`. It doesn't take a lot of code to construct the product morphism by hand:

```
prod :: (a -> b, c -> d) -> (a, c) -> (b, d)
prod (f, g) (x, y) = (f x, g y)
```

Curried versions of `prod`, with a type of `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (a, c) -> (b, d)`, can be found in `base` under the names [`Control.Arrow.(***)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-) or [`Data.Bifunctor.bimap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap). Each of these functions is actually overloaded, so they work at a variety of types, not just the product, such as `bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> Either a c -> Either b d`.

Comment: N.b. either is a sum type

Comment: Note that `prod` is precisely `<<*>>` (from `bifunctors`) at the two-tuple case.